# In python, how can temporarily extract information from a file, and use that information to manipulate the same file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

So I have been coming across this problem a lot lately. Say I have a text file from which I need to read the file, store some values in a list. Next, I want to use that the information in that list to edit another file.
I have been opening the file, store variables in list, close file. open the file again, run the actual analysis and close the file again.
I am thinking that there may be a better way to go about this. I have included an example below...

As always, I will be grateful for any help/suggestions!

I have this file:

```
>sctg_0002_0001  length=2745
TCCCCCTCCCGTACCGGTTTGCGCTATTATACCGGCCTTGAATCGAGCAAAGGCTCCAAACAATTTCATTACAAACAGATTGGGGATGTATGACGTGGCT
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
TTGACACGCTTGTTTCTGATGTCATCACCCATGAAGAGCTGTTATTTGGCCACCTGGCGTTCCTGCCTAAGCGTTGAGTGAATATTAAACACCTCTGCCC
>sctg_0003_0001  length=2175
CAACAACCACTCTTAGCGCTGCTTGCCGCTGCCGATACCGAACGGGATGCGGTAGTCGCTGCTCTGCTCACCCAGACTCACGGTCAGGTTGCCCTGAGTA
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
...
```

When I run this script

```
from Bio import SeqIO
out=open("out.txt","a")
ID=[]
for record in SeqIO.parse("input.fas","fasta"):
    ID.append("_".join(str(record.id).rsplit("_")[1:])) #get the part following the ">"

n=1
for record in SeqIO.parse("input.fas","fasta"):
    if n==len(ID):
        #print >>out, n
        print >>out, "SEQUENCE_ID="+record.id+"e_"+ID[0]+"b"
        print >>out, "SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE ="+record.seq
        print >>out, "="
        n=n+1
        break
    else:
        #print >>out, n
        print >>out, "SEQUENCE_ID="+record.id+"e_"+ID[n]+"b"
        print >>out, "SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE ="+record.seq
        print >>out, "="
        n=n+1
out.close()
```

I get the expected output, however I am thinking there may be a better way to go about it

```
SEQUENCE_ID=sctg_0002_0001e_0003_0001b
SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE =TCCCCCTCCCGTACCGGTTTGCGCTATTATACCGGCCTTGAATCGAGCAAAGGCTCCAAACAATTTCATTACAAACAGATTGGGGATGTATGACGTGGCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTGACACGCTTGTTTCTGATGTCATCACCCATGAAGAGCTGTTATTTGGCCACCTGGCGTTCCTGCCTAAGCGTTGAGTGAATATTAAACACCTCTGCCC
=
SEQUENCE_ID=sctg_0003_0001e_0004_0001b
SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE =CAACAACCACTCTTAGCGCTGCTTGCCGCTGCCGATACCGAACGGGATGCGGTAGTCGCTGCTCTGCTCACCCAGACTCACGGTCAGGTTGCCCTGAGTANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
=
SEQUENCE_ID=sctg_0004_0001e_0005_0001b
SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE =CAACAACCACTCTTAGCGCTGCTTGCCGCTGCCGATACCGAACGGGATGCGGTAGTCGCTGCTCTGCTCACCCAGACTCACGGTCAGGTTGCCCTGAGTANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
=
SEQUENCE_ID=sctg_0005_0001e_0002_0001b
SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE =CAACAACCACTCTTAGCGCTGCTTGCCGCTGCCGATACCGAACGGGATGCGGTAGTCGCTGCTCTGCTCACCCAGACTCACGGTCAGGTTGCCCTGAGTANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
=
```

Comment: The docs for the module you're using explain what you can do under "Input - Multiple Records" -- does that not answer your question? http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-module.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all the processing in only one loop and avoid using the list `ID`. I think it is much cleaner:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
out = open("out.txt", "a")
records = list(SeqIO.parse("input.fas","fasta"))
previous = records[-1]
for record in records:
    id = "_".join(str(record.id).rsplit("_")[1:])
    out.write("SEQUENCE_ID=" + previous.id + "e_" + id + "b\n")
    out.write("SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE =%s\n=\n" % previous.seq)
    previous = record
out.close()
```

Comment: I thought this would happen:  previous = records[-1]
TypeError: 'generator' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: @Stylize Yes, I've changed the answer so now it shouldn't give any problem.